# How to skip the default data frame index, when printing a python data frame in an excel worksheet, using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to print a pandas data frame in an excel sheet, using openpyxl. Until now I have accomplished to print the data frame with the default index . My question is, how  to print it without the default index.
The following example script generates **Table 1** and I would like to know what I need to modify in order to come up with **Table 2**.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df = pd.DataFrame((1,2,3,4,5,6))
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()           
sheet = wb.active 
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         sheet.cell(row=r_idx+1, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save('book1.xlsx')
```

**Table 1**

```
  0

0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
```

**Table 2**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a more elaborated requirement, it's quite easier to go straight with `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`, which already integrates with `openpyxl`.

```
df.to_excel('book1.xlsx')
```

To drop the index, just add:

```
df.to_excel('book1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi Felipe! I know that your answer is correct, but the problem is that in my code I have created a specific excel sheet (font size, colors, etc), using openpyxl, that I would like to use and this is why I am trying to find a solution with the specific library

Comment: Got it. FWIW, since you're not actually using the `idx`, you can still pass the `index=False` when calling `dataframe_to_rows`.